# How to run Android Studio from USB flash drive in Ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, usb, usb-drive

I'm trying to run Android Studio from a USB flash drive in Ubuntu. The laptop only has 15GB of hard drive (Chromebook converted to Linux) I installed jdk locally, but Android Studio I unzip it onto the flash drive. (No problem installing) but when I run Android Studio and create a project, the Gradle in the design area doesn't start and gives me an error (permission problems)…. Has anyone successfully ran Android Studio from a USB flash drive and can share the right configuration?

Answer (score -1):

You are probably using a FAT filesystem on the USB and that's causing the permission problems.

Reformat it as **ext4** and you should be fine.